# How to hide object field names in JSON?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a WEB API that returns a JSON file. I want my JSON to like like this :

```
{
    "PensionDistribution": [{
        "rows": [{
            "uniqueName": "Age"
        }]
    },
    {
        "columns": [{
            "uniqueName": "Year"
        },
        {
            "uniqueName": "Type"
        }]
    },
    {
        "measures": [{
            "uniqueName": "AgentID",
            "aggregation": "count"
        }]
    },
    {
        "fields": {
            "Age": {
                "type": "number",
                "caption": "Age"
            },
            "AgentComputedCompleteName": {
                "type": "string",
                "caption": "Nom complet encodé de l'agent"
            },
            "AgentID": {
                "type": "number",
                "caption": "ID Agent"
            },
            "MatriculeAgent": {
                "type": "string",
                "caption": "Matricule agent"
            },
            "Type": {
                "type": "string",
                "caption": "Type"
            },
            "TypeKey": {
                "type": "string",
                "caption": "Type clé"
            },
            "Year": {
                "type": "string",
                "caption": "Année"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

So I created the classes that will convert my database data into my JSON :

```
public class PivotConfigData
{
    public class Report
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
        public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
        public List<Measure> Measures { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
        public Report()
        {
            Name = "";
            Rows = new List<Row>();
            Columns = new List<Column>();
            Measures = new List<Measure>();
            Fields = new List<Field>();
        }
    }
    public class Row
    {
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Column
    {
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Measure
    {
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
        public string Aggregation { get; set; }
    }
    public class Field
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public FieldAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    }
    public class FieldAttributes
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }
}
```

By using this I get a JSON file like this :

```
{
    "Name": "PensionDistribution",
    "Rows": [{
        "UniqueName": "Age"
    }],
    "Columns": [{
        "UniqueName": "Year"
    },
    {
        "UniqueName": "Type"
    }],
    "Measures": [{
        "UniqueName": "AgentID",
        "Aggregation": "count"
    }],
    "Fields": [{
        "Name": "Age",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "number",
            "Caption": "Age"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "AgentComputedCompleteName",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Caption": "Nom complet encodé de l'agent"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "AgentID",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "number",
            "Caption": "ID Agent"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "MatriculeAgent",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Caption": "Matricule agent"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Type",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Caption": "Type"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "TypeKey",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Caption": "Type clé"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Year",
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Caption": "Année"
        }
    }]
}
```

As you can see, it added the "Name": before "PensionDistribution" but that's not a big deal. It's an issue for the "Fields" collection, as it adds the "Name" and "Attributes", how can I delete or hide those property names ? I tried to add [JsonProperty("")] before my property but it replaces "Name": by "": which is not what I wanted.

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: The problem you have is that Fields is an object with properties named after each Field in your "desired" JSON. Thus, it cannot be translated from the Fields collection specified by your Report class (C#). I would argue that the desired JSON structure as you present it is not generic enough. I wonder how the consumer of this will be able to use it easily (they cannot obtain a collection of Fields for example - rather they would have to hard code access to each of the "Fields" object named properties.

Comment: ... If anything, the second JSON (the one you get from the C# but the one you don't want) would seem easier to work with (both for you and the consumer of the WebAPI). JMO.

Comment: In summary (sorry) - JSON schema shouldn't change between reports. It should have a generic collection of Fields with names, etc, not named properties on an object.

Comment: Yes I know the desired JSON has the Fields in a weird structure but that's the configuration I need to use a pivot control. Finally, I found a solution and I replaced the List <Field> Fields by a Dictionary <string, FieldsAttribute> and got the good format. Thanks for your recommandations !

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer (it may be useful to others - it certainly was an interesting question). :)

Answer (score 1):

Use on unwanted properties attribute [JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm).

For change property name use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewName")]`.

Comment: Thanks but how can I replace the name "Attributes" with the Name property of my field class ? I tried [JsonProperty(Name)] but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't serialize with my code, my web api controller returns an object, which is serialized to JSON automatically

Comment: Then use [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewName")]

Comment: Is it possible to have a variable instead of a constant value ?

Comment: I don't know. In my opinion variable is bad idea. Json always should look same.

Comment: It is not possible because attributes can only be initialized with constants. Changing it requires recompilation at least.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Attributes from JSON.NET (that makes your code dependant on it) you can use the normal serialization attributes of the .NET Framework (`DataMemberAttribute`, `DataContractAttribute`, etc.).

To ignore/remove properties from JSON you can decorate them with the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`.

```
[DataContract]
public class Field
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public FieldAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken Json.NET excludes all values that do not declare `[DataMember]` if `[DataContract]` was found on the class.

Comment: Take a look at this [code from Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L322)

Comment: @Toxantron yeah maybe it works that way. but it is better to explicitly state that the property is ignored. It could be that some has forgotten to decorate the property with an attribute.